# Pascal - мёртвый или живой?

Tags: pascal

Наткнулся в одном вопросе на спор о Паскале. Хоть язык и перестал развиваться - многие считают, что язык по-прежнему выполняет функцию обучения ЯП. Возможно вообще кто-то считает, что с помощью этого языка лучше всего выполнять какие-либо задачи.

Лично моё мнение! Данный язык вообще стоит исключить из обучающей программы, он мёртв, зачем учится на нём программированию? Отлично справится с обучающей функцией язык СИ, который всегда будет актуальным.

И что получается. Человек учит язык Паскаль, потом приходит в ВУЗ и тут начинается СИ, ему приходится изучать новый синтаксис. Паскаль ничем не проще других языков программирования, почему его используют для обучения!?

Пожалуйста, поменяйте моё мнение, почему-то с кем-бы я не спорил мне без аргументов отвечают что паскаль для учёбы. Да ничему хорошему он не учит. Когда был в школе учитель пытался мне преподавать этот язык, я как дурак потратил несколько дней на его изучение, скачал книжечку, после чего встретил нормального человека на форуме он мне сказал что Паскаль  - гавно, указал на Basic, не долго на нём задерживаясь перешёл на СИ. И сейчас легко понимаю многие актуальные языки программирования, но приходилось разбираться в паскале, когда занимался репетиторством - там труднее намного.

**Итак, слушаю Ваши мнения по этому поводу. Зачем этот язык? Не убрать бы нафиг его из школьной, в некоторых случаях ВУЗовской программы?**

Comment: [Какие вопросы не стоит задавать?](http://hashcode.ru/faq/#heading8)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, в редких случаях стоит. Мне стало интересно, почему Pascal так защищают. Тут сидят профи с огромным опытом, надеялся объяснят. И я наконец с уверенностью смогу опустить тех, кто мне будет втирать про "божественный язык - Pascal", либо согласится, если меня переубедят.

Comment: Ответ - мёртвый.

Comment: >И я наконец с уверенностью смогу опустить тех, кто мне будет втирать

пожалуйста, постарайтесь избегать подзаборной лексики типа "опустить", "втирать" и тд - вы же не быдло какое-нибудь, надеюсь?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вопрос на самом деле любопытный. 
Начну с "мертвости" Паскаля. У Паскаля есть пара  проблем, способных его умертвить - в свое время небезызвестную контору Borland понесло в эксперименты типа Ddelphi.NET, благодаря которым долгое время Delphi 7 оставался последней надежной версией среды и языка. Потом упавшее знамя подхватила другая компания, но время было упущено - пришел век веб-разработки, затем мобильных приложений, а ниша паскаля оставалась в десктопных приложениях и прочих сегментах, чей процентна рынке сокращался. Надо сказать, что Embarcadero подхватила это упавшее знамя с пользой, проделав много всякой полезной работы, вроде даже на нем сейчас можно писать что-то кросплатформенное, но поезд похоже ушел (плюс их странная политика лицензирования тоже не придает популярности их продуктам) В общем, все эти смутные времена не прошли даром, и для многих Delphi-программистов  в силу разных причин время  до сих пор остановилось на Ddelphi 7, с которого они никуда не слезают. 
Из выгшесказанного вытекает нижеследующее: назвать его мертвым нельзя - есть тысячи тонн легаси-кода, который надо сопровождать сейчас и лет на 30 в будущем, есть всяческие достойные похвал потуги от Embarcadero, из которых может выйти что-то путное. Но все же звездные час его вероятно прошел.

Теперь о главном. Цитирую:

> Лично моё мнение! Данный язык вообще стоит исключить из обучающей программы, он мёртв, зачем учится на нём программированию? Отлично справится с обучающей функцией язык СИ, который всегда будет актуальным.

Вы в вашем вопросе и конкретно в этой цитате сильно неправы - очень уж категорично и неаргументированно судите, с преобладанием эмоций, а не рассуждений. 
Паскаль имеет ценность как неплохой выбор для обучения вне зависимости от того, насколько широко или узко он используется в продакшн-разработке. Потому что в институтах (в нормальных во всяком случае) изучают  **не сам Паскаль**, а основы программирования и алгоримизации **с помощью** Паскаля.

Паскаль хорош для обучения вот чем: ясным и человекопонятным синтаксисом, где управляющие конструкции кодируются не с помощью скобочек, значков и всяческих символов, а с помощью слов человеческого языка (сравните человекопонятные begin end и краткие, но ни с чем логически не связанные фигурные скобки). Это впоследствии многословность синтаксиса Паскаля становится костью в горле, а для новичка это своеобразный мостик между его человеческой логикой и логикой компьютерной программы.
Также паскаль хорош для обучения своей строгостью - статическая типизация, переменные  могут объявляться только в отведенных блоках, а не где попало (это потом по мере роста опыта станет неудобно, а пока приучает новичка к порядку в программе), отсутствуют всяческие подводные камни и неочевидные моменты, коими, скажем, набит С++. Твакже в отличие скажем от C#/Java паскаль не навязывает вам сразу же ООП (бесспорно, вещь полезная, но до него новичку еще надо дорасти). То есть Паскаль хорош своей простотой, очевидностью,  человекопонятностью, строгостью, не приучает к расхлябанности и костылям - в общем-то все это хорошо подходит для обучения новичков. 
Не стану утверждать, что паскаль лучший язык для старта, но он явно лучше многих.

Говорить же о том, что, дескать, товарищи, начинайте учиться с Си/Java/C#/etc, он пригодится вам в будущем, а паскаль не пригодится - это, конечно, не лишено смысла, но и огромной практической пользы не имеет. Практика показывает, что к концу института выпускник обычно еще не имеет глубоких знаний по языку, но  уже имеет достаточный опыт чтобы безболезненно перейти с одного языка на другой. Поэтому переход с паскаля на что-то еще проблем не составляет

> Не убрать бы нафиг его из школьной, в некоторых случаях ВУЗовской программы?

ну это решаем не мы, и, пожалуй, даже не Министерство Образования. В каждом конкретном ВУЗе обычно делают свой выбор насчет того, на каком языке обучать студентов

З.Ы. Сам к Паскалю отношения не имею, не писал на нем со студенческой скамьи, а потому особой любовью и пристрастностью к нему не страдаю. Однако же именно в качестве обучающего языка польза в нем есть. Просто процент его применения в бизнес-проектах - это уже совсем другая история, к обучению студентов отношения не имеющая

Answer (score 6):

Для тех кто пишет глубоко побоку на каком языке писать, а для тех кто пиписьками меряется есть разница живой язык или нет.
Синтаксис языка выучить проще, чем понять хотя бы азы программирования.

холивар детектед, тему закрою.

Comment: нифига себе. Сколько агрессии

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что тема до сих пор не закрыта. Но раз уж это так, то, конечно же, выскажу мнение.

Придание такой важности живости/мёртвости языка сразу выдаёт неверное понимание того, что такое обучение. Живой язык в качестве обучающего предпочтительнее мёртвого лишь в очень специальном сегменте обучения, в рамках которого происходит прокачка практически полезных навыков. С одной стороны, мы не можем исключить этот сегмент, поскольку это всё-таки обучение. Но, с другой стороны, надо понимать, что это уровень ПТУ, и обучение к этому не сводится. Когда мы говорим об образовании, пусть даже о профессиональном, мы имеем в виду не столько ПТУ, сколько университеты.

А университеты работают по чуть-чуть другому принципу. В них не конкретные навыки помогают прокачать, а стараются научить правильно думать. Исходя из того, что это поможет в будущем самостоятельно прокачивать нужные навыки всю жизнь. А для такой задачи мёртвый язык как минимум не хуже, а может даже и лучше. По крайней мере, обучение на мёртвом языке минимизирует соблазн написать игру, что сказывается на обучении положительно, поскольку уменьшает вероятность утраты интереса к чистым абстракциям и скатывания на уровень ПТУ. Сейчас это особенно опасно. Раньше для программирования игр нужно было глубоко понимать математику. Сейчас же для программировании графики существуют готовые движки.

Что же касается конкретно Паскаля, то он лучше всего подходит для обучения уже хотя бы потому, что ничего лучше для этой цели человечество пока не придумало. У него есть множество недостатков. Но такого баланса между простотой и степенью близости к машине не обеспечивает ни один другой известный мне язык. Простота критически важна для сохранения мотивации при обучении. А степень близости к машине критически важна для того, чтобы научиться программировать машину.

Есть более простые языки... например, Питон. Но на нём никак нельзя научиться тому, что в действительности происходит в компьютере. На нём вообще почти ничему нельзя научиться. Скажем, системе типов на Питоне научиться сложновато. С его помощью можно только понять, насколько система типов важна, если ты уже знаешь, что это, и что такое вообще бывает. Вот для того, чтобы это понять, Питон подходит идеально...

Есть языки более близкие к машине... например, C и C++. Но они слишком сложны для того, чтобы с них начинать. На одном из моих предыдущих мест работы однажды взяли на работу стажёра без опыта вообще. Исходя из того, что он научится программировать на С++ в процессе работы. Решили, что нормально. Мы же как-то сами научились C++. А он вроде неглупый малый. Тоже сможет. Через три недели он уволился со словами о том, что вообще не хочет быть программистом.

Answer (score -6):

я советую всем учить первыми +сы. тот кто пишет на плюсах, сможет с легкостью писать любому другом языке. паскаль дохлый уже давно. толку от него нету вообще!